# AVFoundation: how to resize frames in sampleBuffer (AVCaptureSessionPreset) does not affect it

Tags: macos, avfoundation, video-capture, video-processing

I am trying to capture video frames from my macBook camera and process them on the fly (for later face detection). To reduce memory usage, I want to reduce the capture resolution from the preset value 1200x720 to 640x480.

Here is my code to setup the Capture Session:

```
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    if ([_session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480]){
        [_session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
        NSLog(@"resolution preset changed");
    }

    // configure input
    _camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    _deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_camera error:nil];


    // configure output
    _videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary* newSettings = @{ (NSString*) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
    _videoOutput.videoSettings = newSettings;
    //discard if the data output queue is blocked
    [_videoOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];

    // process frames on another queue
    dispatch_queue_t videoDataOutputQueue;
    videoDataOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("VideoDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [_videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:videoBufferDelegate queue:videoDataOutputQueue];

    [_session addInput:_deviceInput];
    [_session addOutput:_videoOutput];

    [_session startRunning];
```

After this, the session sets up appropriately, it logs "resolution preset changed" correctly and forwards the video data to the delegate on another queue to process it. When I inspect `session.sessionPreset`, it says that the preset is `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480`.

Now in the delegate:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
        didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
        fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    //get the image from buffer, transform it to CIImage
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    self.image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
```

When inspecting `self.image.extent.size`, it shows and incorrect size of 1200x720, as if I had not changed the preset before. Even when inspecting the method's arguement `sampleBuffer`, it shows the dimension as 1200x720.

I browsed the internet and the apple reference for a couple of hours now, but could not manage to find a solution. I hope you can save me!

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution by myself (or at least a workaround). Commenting out the following lines led to the intended changes of the buffer's resolution:

```
    NSDictionary* settings = @{ (NSString*) kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
    _videoOutput.videoSettings = settings;
```

My assumption is, that setting these compression settings results in an overwriting of the AVCaptureSessionPreset. However, I find it not completely clear why this should be the case (compression settings shouldn't have an influence on resolution settings, right?).